# Best practices implementing Security in multiple Web application

Tags: java, security, design-patterns, spring-security

We are using Spring Security and it is working fine in the single web application. Now, I need to create another Web application with Spring security. In the first application the user can sell his/her stuff (e.g. EBay). The second app which I am creating now, it is for general users where he can save his general preferences, searches, save some items he looked at etc. He may/may not be the existing user. So the difference between the two users are:
User 1 (existing user): Can post his stuff for sale.
User 2: He/she should be able to login. Save his general activities etc. & if he/she wants to sell his/her item, he/she needs to go thru the additional steps for verification.

All this cannot be done in just one application due to some reasons. My question is on how to handle the security? Should I create separate security filters for each applications or is there a way to use common security implementation who can manager both of these application. Please provide your feedback, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap both components in two different webapps, each will have his own spring security web filter infrastructure.
So in principle there will be a security session for each web application, to be backed by whatever authentication system you use.
If you use JDBC then the user would have to login twice.

If you want your customers to only login once, you can for example use a token based system.
When you cross link from webapp 1 to webapp 2, you could hook the links up to a redirect servlet.
The servlet then generates a token, persists it in a database and forwards the user with the token in the url to the other webapp.
In spring security you can then implement your own [PRE_AUTH_FILTER](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters) which reads out the token, verifies if it is persisted in the Database.
For security reasons you should make these tokens only one use.